# Taking arbitrary length input from stdin using scanf

Tags: c, stdin, scanf

So one of the ways to take user-keyboard input in C I know is as follows:

```
char buffer[LENGTH_KNOWN] = "";
scanf("%s",buffer);
```

I was wondering if there is any way to take arbitrary length user input. I tried something as follows but I ended up getting a segfault.

```
char* buffer = "";
scanf("%s",buffer);
printf("%s",buffer);
```

However this seems to work:

```
char* buffer = "TEST........keeps going....................."
scanf("%s",buffer);
printf("%s",buffer);
```

Can anybody explain why I am getting this error and is there any easy way out to scanf arbitrary user input without using malloc and checking buffer overflow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is going to mark the end of the arbitrary length input?  How arbitrary is the arbitrary length?  1 KiB; 4 KiB; 4 MiB; 4 GiB; 4 TiB; bigger?  You can protect yourself from damage with `%4095s` if LENGTH_KNOWN is 4096 (or bigger).  You might want to use `%4095[^\n]\n` to read up to 4095 non-newlines into the buffer and a newline after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually both are wrong since you can't write to a string literal (in both your examples `buffer` points to a string literal).

It's impossible to get arbitrarily-long input via a single `scanf`. You need to get input in a loop and keep adding to a real buffer.

> is there any easy way out to scanf arbitrary user input without using
>   malloc and checking buffer overflow

Use a ready-made function that does it for you. Something like `getline(3)` (non-standard unfortunately).

```
ssize_t getline (char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)
```

> This function reads an entire line from stream, storing the text
>   (including the newline and a terminating null character) in a buffer
>   and storing the buffer address in `*lineptr`.

Answer (score 1):

`char *buffer = "...";` is totally wrong. It is not how you allocate memory because the thing in double quotes is a string literal and it is read-only. You can allocate memory like this:

```
char buffer[1024];
```

or dynamically using malloc:

```
char *buffer = malloc(1024);

/* .... */

free(buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 char* buffer = "";
 scanf("%s",buffer);
 printf("%s",buffer);
```

In the above your code you are not allocating memory for the buffer, so allocate memory for the buffer and read the values into buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You Never know how much bytes you might read and hence allocate the memory accordingly. So I guess you need to get input in a loop and add in into buffer.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* buffer;

buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024); // 1024 is max user input length, or use whatever you want..

scanf("%s", buffer);

buffer = realloc (buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1); // re-allocating the buffer according  to user input..( + 1 for counting NULL character)

printf("%s",buffer);
```